# Can the help page on what a good answer is be updated with specifics?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The [How do I write a good answer?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) page seems to be generic SE help page rather than specific to Code Review; can this page be updated with specifics to this site? Is there a help page on how not to answer a question?

I know this question has almost been asked before with [this question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/what-makes-for-a-good-answer). Two things prompted me to ask this question:

1. I want to improve my answers.
2. A couple of weeks ago I voted down a code only answer but couldn't find a good reference to point the poster to. Two people backed me up in comments and the poster eventually removed the answer (how not to lose a point when voting down an answer). **I'd rather keep a poster interested by pointing them to a reference than losing them from Code Review**.

In my search for how to improve my questions I found the following questions which were enlightening and educational but didn't really answer my questions:

1. [Short Answers and Code Only Answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers)
2. [Is just reviewing the code good enough of an answer?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/907/is-just-reviewing-the-code-good-enough-of-an-answer)
3. [A guide to code review for stack overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)
4. [Checklist or general directions on how to write a good CR-ish answer](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/checklist-or-general-directions-on-how-to-write-a-good-cr-ish-answer)
5. [Does a good posted answer make the question on topic regardless of content?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/does-a-good-posted-answer-make-the-question-on-topic-regardless-of-content)

Comment: If anyone posts an answer with a suggestion for how we should write a new page or modify the existing one, the moderators can make the change happen.

Comment: [This draft](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/5091/9357) is waiting. If you think it's good, upvote it. If you have improvements to suggest, edit it. If you want to open a discussion about it, then keep this question open.

Comment: @200_success That's an old draft, what's the status of implementing it?

Comment: @Mast Waiting for indication of consensus. Upvote if you think it's good.

Comment: @200_success I'll keep this question open for a while. I don't know how to improve the draft on the comment I left.

Comment: @200_success I've upvoted it a year ago.